# Python subprocess with awk and pipes

Tags: python, bash, awk, subprocess

I have the following statements in my Python script:

```
year = '1966'
file = 'test.txt'
cmd = "awk '{FS="|"}{if ($2 == %s) print $1}' %s | sort -n | uniq | wc" % (year, file)
bla = run_command(cmd)
```

where `fun_command()` is the function:

```
def run_command(command):                                     
  process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, command], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  retcode = process.wait()
  if retcode != 0:
    raise Exception, "Problem running command: " + command
  stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
  return stdout
```

The following output is produced:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: I have to say this, calling `awk` from `python` is like (to misquote Larry Wall) having an Uzi machine gun then hitting someone over the head with it.

Comment: Know, but I use it for prototyping (only).

Comment: Combining lists and `shell=True` is usually a bad idea. However, `sys.executable` is the *Python* interpreter being run, not a shell interpreter. Use `Popen(command, shell=True, ...)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"awk '{FS="|"}{if ($2 == %s) print $1}' %s | sort -n | uniq | wc"`
Here you need to escape inner `"|"`

`"awk '{FS=\"|\"}{if ($2 == %s) print $1}' %s | sort -n | uniq | wc"`

Comment: Any idea why empty string (i.e., `b''`) is returned. I test the command in the shell and it works fine.

Comment: `wait()` waits for the process to terminate. `communicate()` interacts with process, but after wait it is already terminated. Check if pipe is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.executable` is the *Python* interpreter currently running, so you are trying to execute your shell code as Python code. Just use

```
def run_command(command):                                     
  process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  retcode = process.wait()
  if retcode != 0:
    raise Exception, "Problem running command: " + command
  stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
  return stdout
```